# NullPointerException of datasource in initiating the connection pool

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, database-connection, connection-pooling

So I have a code in the **context.xml** which contains the information for the connection of my database

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<Resources name="jdbc/murach" auth="Containter"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/murach"
    username="root" password="root"
    maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
    logAbandoned="true" removeAbandoned="true"
    removeAbandonedTimeout="60" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

 <ResourceLink name="jdbc/murach"
         global="jdbc/mydb"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

While for the **Connection Pool** I created a class to initiate and to connect it to the database. the error begins in the method of `getConnection()`. May I ask what should i really put in the lookup for it to work. By the way the error is `NullPointerException` in the return of the `datasource.getConnection()`

```
package lars.data;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;


public class ConnectionPool {
    private static ConnectionPool pool = null;
    private static DataSource dataSource = null;

    private ConnectionPool() {
        try {
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            dataSource = (DataSource) ic.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/murach");
            System.out.print(dataSource);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static synchronized ConnectionPool getInstance() {
        if (pool == null) {
            pool = new ConnectionPool();
        }
        return pool;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            return dataSource.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void freeConnection(Connection c) {
        try {
            c.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try this say?  InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            dataSource = (DataSource) ic.lookup("jdbc/murach"); or try with ctx.bind (). It all depends on where you created logical name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your problem is in the configuration of your `ResourceLink` especially the value of the attribute `global` that should match with the value defined in your `Resource`, it should be:

```
 <ResourceLink name="jdbc/murach"
         global="jdbc/murach"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

> **global**:   The name of the linked global resource in the global JNDI
>   context.
>
> **name**: The name of the resource link to be created, relative to the
>   `java:comp/env` context.

**NB 1:** The name of the node that defines a resource is `Resource` not `Resources`. In other words it should be:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/murach" ... />
```

**NB 2:** You should try `ic.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/murach")`

Comment: The code that you suggested worked! I just change the resource link and the resources into resource and it worked. Thank you very much @Nicolas-filotto !